# L2S aggregate binding pain

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a fairly simple model:

```
public class Delivery
{
    public int DeliveryId { get; set; }
    public int OverId { get; set; }
    public int Ball { get; set; }
    public int Runs { get; set; }

    public Player Player { get; set; }
}
```

All I want to do is have my collection of Delivery objects grouped by Player so that I can then perform some stats calculations on the results in my MVC3 view.

I'm almost there, but between the L2S query and my model binding declaration, I just can't get the two to marry up.

Doing it this way almost works:

```
var batting = from d in deliveries
              where d.Over.IsBatting == true
              group d by d.Player into player
              select player;

return View(batting);
```

But the view bindings are a mess.
Bit of help?

EDIT:
Here's my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<IGrouping<Cricket.Models.Player, Cricket.Models.Delivery>>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Batting";
}

<h2>Batting</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            OverId
        </th>
        <th>
            Ball
        </th>
        <th>
            Runs
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var Item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
@*            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.DeliveryId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.DeliveryId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.DeliveryId })
*@        </td>
        <td>
            @Item.Key
        </td>
        <td>
            @*item.Ball *@
        </td>
        <td>
            @Item.Sum(x => x.Runs)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: query has no problem can u state specifically (with some code) where is the problem. you may use projections in the query to build your model & then pass it to the view

Comment: The query itself isn't the problem. My problem is, how should I bind this result (IEnumerable<IGrouping<Player, Delivery>>) to my page? At the moment, I'm getting a null value for the key and the total number of Runs for my Sum(x => x.Runs) statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a ViewModel like

```
public class VMPlayerRuns
{
   public Player _Player{get;set;}
   public int Runs{get;set;}
}
```

and you can modify your query little bit like

```
var batting = from d in deliveries
              where d.Over.IsBatting == true
              group d by d.Player into player
              from p in player  
              select new VMPlayerRuns{Player = p.Key, p.Sum(x=>x.Runs)};
```

Now you can bind this viewmodel to your view rather than complex clumsy grouping. 
**Note:**There may be some syntax errors in query but this is whole idea of projecting grouping to your viewmodels

Comment: Of course! That'll do just fine. Sometimes I can't see the forest for the trees.